How to wait for all necessary network calls to get completed before redirection?
I am managing an application that consists of both AngularJS and Angular components within the same website. The AngularJS application serves as the entry point, from which users can navigate to the Angular application. During this transition, the files of the previous application are unloaded and replaced by those of the new application to meet its requirements.
In the Angular application, I handle various asynchronous network calls triggered by user events through an event-based communication system. These events can originate from any part of the application, with corresponding network calls being made upon event subscription.
A significant challenge arises when certain events not only initiate network calls but also trigger user redirection back to the AngularJS application. The network call logic and redirection logic are located in different parts of the application. Consequently, the redirection process interrupts the ongoing network calls, leading to a 500 error with a "cancelled" status in the network tab.
To address this issue, I need a method to ensure that all network calls are completed before executing the redirection. This involves synchronizing the asynchronous nature of both network calls and the redirection process to prevent premature termination of the calls. How can I achieve this synchronization to ensure network calls finish successfully before the redirection occurs?
I thought of one solution to not send network calls for those events that initiate redirection, but I want a more robust solution for my problem

Seems like you're trying to coordinate multiple async redirections here?  (or am I misunderstanding?)  Seems like you should bite the bullet and create a single up-to-date app instead of redirecting between two different ones.

Thanks for the idea but, The angularjs application is legacy application and cannot be directly written in new angular. We are migrating towards react js gradually, but it will take time and till then I need a robust solution to it.

Are the redirections done from frontend or backend?

They are done from frontend.

you have to ensure that you await responses... which could mean a significant restructuring.  All this legacy support will end up costing you more time in the long run than just re-writing the whole app.  (since you'll need to do that anyway...) I think my advice remains the same, but maybe someone else has an idea.  It'd help if you showed some code that illustrates the problem.
